# Bootstrap + Angular: modal with dynamic image

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am new to Boostrap and I am trying to open a modal with an image inside.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal

The fact is that I have a lot of image on my page and I do not want to do a single modal per image. So I tried to load them dynamically.

Now on, when I click on the image nothing appear, but in the inspector I clearly see that the modal is there, totally transparent though. Any idea on what I have done wrong? Thanks!

In order to do this here is what I have done:

*thing.html*

```html
[...] // Below the <img> tag that i want to click on
<img src="../../assets/img/photosloc/photo.jpg" class="card-img-top" (click)='showModal(".the/path/to/the/photo.jpg")'>
[...]//Below my modal that should pop
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true" >
  <div class=" modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="modal-content" id="modalImg">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*thing.component.ts*

```js
constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }
  modal: any;
  modalImg : any;
  span : any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    this.modalImg = document.getElementById("modalImg");
    this.span = document.getElementById("close");
  }
showModal(imgPath) {
    console.log(imgPath); 
    this.modal.style.display = "block";
    this.modalImg.src = imgPath;
  }

 closeModal(){
   this.modal.style.display = "none";
 }
```

Comment: Well, `angular` doesn't play well with `bootstrap`'s javascript files. Your best bet is to use one of the libraries that integrates the two. While there may be others, I know of two: `ng-bootstrap` (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) and `ngx-bootstrap` (https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/).

Answer (score 0):

do you have your index.html well configured? it needs jquery to work

in index.html

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: is it the same if i added these scripts in my angular.json file? in the script[] part.